# Issue installing server 2008R2 on hyper-v on a 2012 host

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I am installing a 2008R2 standard edition server on a hyper-v running on a server 2012R2 standard.
Every time I install the server I am getting the following error, followed by a restart which causes a blue-screen.

[image: Error]

- I have set the server to set memory, 4096MB.
- I've redownloaded the ISO, and rebooted the server.
- I've tried the steps from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/error-message-the-computer-restarted-unexpectedly/b770f14d-e345-e011-90b6-1cc1de79d2e2

The only thing I can find in the event viewer is:
[image: EventViewer]

But this seems unrelated. And I doubt I can resolve it untill the OS is fully installed.

What could I be dealing with? I'm inclined to think corrupt memory in the host server, but I'm not entirely familiar with Hyper-V and would like some alternatives before reviewing hardware.

Comment: What hardware are you running Hyper-V on?

Comment: Proliant ML370 G5 series.

Comment: I also run Hyper-V on a G5 (at home), it's never given me any issues. Does it fail at the same point each time?

Comment: It seems to fail around the time of the first reboot every time.

Comment: I'd grab a trial Server 2012 .iso and give that a go. Failing that, I'd swap out RAM pairs and see if you have any luck there.

Comment: What gen VM are you using, and with a SCSI or IDE controller? I'd try gen 1 with IDE first off.  Or similar to @tombull89's suggestion, try to install to a second VM using same 2012 R2 install media you used on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using en_windows_server_2008_r2_with_sp1_x64_dvd.iso and this version succeded in installing.

Perhaps I made a mistake and used my old copy of en_windows_server_2008_r2_standard_enterprise_datacenter_and_web_with_sp1_debug_checked_build_x64_dvd after downloading a fresh ISO. Or something happened on both downloads...

Regardless, the issue was with the ISO, and downloading a different one fixed it.